# MemSQL takes 15GB memory for 10MB of data

Tags: memory, singlestore

I have installed memsql 5.1.2 in following manner with following resources.

> Google cloud server
>
> HDD: 100GB
>
> Machine type:  n1-standard-4 (4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory)

**Implementation:**

2 MEMSQL NODES running on same machine on the following ports

> 3306  Master Aggregator
>
> 3307  Leaf

**Resource Utilization:**

> Memory 14.16 GB / 14.69 GB
>
> Paging 0 B/s
>
> Database size - 10MB

```
1818    memsql  1.1%    77% /var/lib/memsql/leaf-3307/memsqld --defaults-file=/var/lib/memsql/leaf-3307/memsql.cnf --pid-file=/var/lib/memsql/leaf-3307/data/memsqld.pid --user=memsql
2736    memsql  0.3%    16% /var/lib/memsql/master-3306/memsqld --defaults-file=/var/lib/memsql/master-330
```

**Note:** There is no Swap memory implemented in the server.

Database size is taken by running a query on information_schema.TABLES.

All data resides as row store since we have to run queries by considering many relationships among tables.

As soon as the memsql is up the memory goes up to 70% and it keep on increasing and after 2-3 hours memsql gives the following error when try connect with it and connection also can not be done after that.

```
OperationalError: (1836, "Leaf 'xx.xxx.x.xx':3307 failed while executing this query. Try re-running the query.")
[Mon Mar 27 09:26:31.163455 2017] [:error] [pid 1718] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9956]
```

The only solution is to restart the server since it has taken up all the memory.

What I can do for this? Is there an issue in the way it's implemented? Any logs should I attach here?

`Show status extended;` query gives the following result

```
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Aborted_clients                     | 48                                                                     |
| Aborted_connects                    | 1                                                                      |
| Bytes_received                      | 85962135                                                               |
| Bytes_sent                          | 545322701                                                              |
| Connections                         | 1626                                                                   |
| Max_used_connections                | 69                                                                     |
| Queries                             | 364793                                                                 |
| Questions                           | 364793                                                                 |
| Threads_cached                      | 19                                                                     |
| Threads_connected                   | 50                                                                     |
| Threads_created                     | 69                                                                     |
| Threads_running                     | 1                                                                      |
| Threads_background                  | 1                                                                      |
| Threads_idle                        | 0                                                                      |
| Ready_queue                         | 0                                                                      |
| Idle_queue                          | 0                                                                      |
| Context_switches                    | 1626                                                                   |
| Context_switch_misses               | 0                                                                      |
| Uptime                              | 22270                                                                  |
| Auto_attach_remaining_seconds       | 0                                                                      |
| Data_directory                      | /var/lib/memsql/leaf-3307/data                                         |
| Plancache_directory                 | /var/lib/memsql/leaf-3307/plancache                                    |
| Transaction_logs_directory          | /var/lib/memsql/leaf-3307/data/logs                                    |
| Segments_directory                  | /var/lib/memsql/leaf-3307/data/columns                                 |
| Snapshots_directory                 | /var/lib/memsql/leaf-3307/data/snapshots                               |
| Threads_waiting_for_disk_space      | 0                                                                      |
| Seconds_until_expiration            | -1                                                                     |
| License_key                         | 11111111111111111111111111111111                                       |
| License_type                        | community                                                              |
| Query_compilations                  | 62                                                                     |
| Query_compilation_failures          | 0                                                                      |
| GCed_versions_last_sweep            | 0                                                                      |
| Average_garbage_collection_duration | 21 ms                                                                  |
| Total_server_memory                 | 9791.4 MB                                                              |
| Alloc_thread_stacks                 | 70.0 MB                                                                |
| Malloc_active_memory                | 1254.7 (+0.0) MB                                                       |
| Malloc_cumulative_memory            | 7315.5 (+0.2) MB                                                       |
| Buffer_manager_memory               | 1787.8 MB                                                              |
| Buffer_manager_cached_memory        | 77.2 (-0.1) MB                                                         |
| Buffer_manager_unrecycled_memory    | 0.0 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_skiplist_tower                | 263.8 MB                                                               |
| Alloc_variable                      | 501.4 MB                                                               |
| Alloc_large_variable                | 2.4 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_table_primary                 | 752.6 MB                                                               |
| Alloc_deleted_version               | 92.9 MB                                                                |
| Alloc_internal_key_node             | 72.1 MB                                                                |
| Alloc_hash_buckets                  | 459.1 MB                                                               |
| Alloc_table_metadata_cache          | 1.1 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_unit_images                   | 34.8 MB                                                                |
| Alloc_unit_ifn_thunks               | 0.6 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_object_code_images            | 11.6 MB                                                                |
| Alloc_compiled_unit_sections        | 17.3 MB                                                                |
| Alloc_databases_list_entry          | 17.9 MB                                                                |
| Alloc_plan_cache                    | 0.1 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_replication_large             | 232.0 MB                                                               |
| Alloc_durability_large              | 7239.1 MB                                                              |
| Alloc_sharding_partitions           | 0.1 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_security                      | 0.1 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_log_replay                    | 0.9 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_client_connection             | 3.0 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_protocol_packet               | 6.1 (+0.1) MB                                                          |
| Alloc_large_incremental             | 0.8 MB                                                                 |
| Alloc_table_memory                  | 2144.2 MB                                                              |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_16            | allocs:10877846  alloc_MB:166.0  buffer_MB:179.0  cached_buffer_MB:1.9 |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_24            | allocs:4275659  alloc_MB:97.9  buffer_MB:106.8  cached_buffer_MB:1.9   |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_32            | allocs:2875801  alloc_MB:87.8  buffer_MB:93.4  cached_buffer_MB:1.9    |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_40            | allocs:724489  alloc_MB:27.6  buffer_MB:31.0  cached_buffer_MB:1.2     |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_48            | allocs:377060  alloc_MB:17.3  buffer_MB:19.8  cached_buffer_MB:0.9     |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_56            | allocs:228720  alloc_MB:12.2  buffer_MB:14.0  cached_buffer_MB:0.8     |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_64            | allocs:150214  alloc_MB:9.2  buffer_MB:10.1  cached_buffer_MB:0.2      |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_72            | allocs:35264  alloc_MB:2.4  buffer_MB:2.9  cached_buffer_MB:0.0        |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_80            | allocs:14920  alloc_MB:1.1  buffer_MB:1.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0        |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_88            | allocs:5582  alloc_MB:0.5  buffer_MB:0.6  cached_buffer_MB:0.0         |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_104           | allocs:8075  alloc_MB:0.8  buffer_MB:1.0  cached_buffer_MB:0.0         |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_128           | allocs:8892  alloc_MB:1.1  buffer_MB:1.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0         |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_160           | allocs:17614  alloc_MB:2.7  buffer_MB:3.0  cached_buffer_MB:0.0        |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_200           | allocs:30454  alloc_MB:5.8  buffer_MB:6.9  cached_buffer_MB:0.6        |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_248           | allocs:4875  alloc_MB:1.2  buffer_MB:1.5  cached_buffer_MB:0.2         |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_312           | allocs:371  alloc_MB:0.1  buffer_MB:0.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0          |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_384           | allocs:30  alloc_MB:0.0  buffer_MB:0.1  cached_buffer_MB:0.0           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_480           | allocs:11  alloc_MB:0.0  buffer_MB:0.1  cached_buffer_MB:0.0           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_600           | allocs:57  alloc_MB:0.0  buffer_MB:0.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_752           | allocs:62  alloc_MB:0.0  buffer_MB:0.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_936           | allocs:42  alloc_MB:0.0  buffer_MB:0.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_1168          | allocs:106  alloc_MB:0.1  buffer_MB:0.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0          |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_1480          | allocs:126  alloc_MB:0.2  buffer_MB:0.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0          |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_1832          | allocs:0  alloc_MB:0.0  buffer_MB:0.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.2            |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_2288          | allocs:1  alloc_MB:0.0  buffer_MB:0.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.1            |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_2832          | allocs:33  alloc_MB:0.1  buffer_MB:1.1  cached_buffer_MB:0.2           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_3528          | allocs:16  alloc_MB:0.1  buffer_MB:0.5  cached_buffer_MB:0.1           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_4504          | allocs:49  alloc_MB:0.2  buffer_MB:0.8  cached_buffer_MB:0.0           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_5680          | allocs:66  alloc_MB:0.4  buffer_MB:1.2  cached_buffer_MB:0.0           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_6224          | allocs:30  alloc_MB:0.2  buffer_MB:1.0  cached_buffer_MB:0.1           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_7264          | allocs:94  alloc_MB:0.7  buffer_MB:1.5  cached_buffer_MB:0.0           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_9344          | allocs:70  alloc_MB:0.6  buffer_MB:2.6  cached_buffer_MB:0.2           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_11896         | allocs:14  alloc_MB:0.2  buffer_MB:2.4  cached_buffer_MB:1.2           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_14544         | allocs:7  alloc_MB:0.1  buffer_MB:2.4  cached_buffer_MB:1.9            |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_18696         | allocs:18  alloc_MB:0.3  buffer_MB:3.2  cached_buffer_MB:1.9           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_21816         | allocs:4  alloc_MB:0.1  buffer_MB:0.4  cached_buffer_MB:0.0            |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_26184         | allocs:6  alloc_MB:0.1  buffer_MB:0.9  cached_buffer_MB:0.2            |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_32728         | allocs:13  alloc_MB:0.4  buffer_MB:2.4  cached_buffer_MB:1.4           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_43648         | allocs:12  alloc_MB:0.5  buffer_MB:1.4  cached_buffer_MB:0.2           |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_65472         | allocs:7  alloc_MB:0.4  buffer_MB:2.8  cached_buffer_MB:1.9            |
| Alloc_variable_bucket_130960        | allocs:3  alloc_MB:0.4  buffer_MB:2.2  cached_buffer_MB:1.9            |
| Alloc_variable_cached_buffers       | 21.4 MB                                                                |
| Alloc_variable_allocated            | 438.7 MB                                                               |
| Successful_read_queries             | 9048                                                                   |
| Successful_write_queries            | 19096                                                                  |
| Failed_read_queries                 | 0                                                                      |
| Failed_write_queries                | 4                                                                      |
| Rows_returned_by_reads              | 75939                                                                  |
| Rows_affected_by_writes             | 245                                                                    |
| Execution_time_of_reads             | 7864 ms                                                                |
| Execution_time_of_write             | 180311 ms                                                              |
| Transaction_buffer_wait_time        | 0 ms                                                                   |
| Transaction_log_flush_wait_time     | 0 ms                                                                   |
| Row_lock_wait_time                  | 0 ms                                                                   |
| Ssl_accept_renegotiates             | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_accepts                         | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits             | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_client_connects                 | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates            | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_depth                | 18446744073709551615                                                   |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_mode                 | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_default_timeout                 | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_finished_accepts                | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_finished_connects               | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_session_cache_hits              | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_session_cache_misses            | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows         | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_session_cache_size              | 20480                                                                  |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts          | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_sessions_reused                 | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries      | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_verify_depth                    | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_verify_mode                     | 0                                                                      |
| Ssl_cipher                          |                                                                        |
| Ssl_cipher_list                     |                                                                        |
| Ssl_version                         |                                                                        |
| Ssl_session_cache_mode              | SERVER                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you start by attaching the output of SHOW STATUS on the leaf 3307 node? See https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001091386-What-Is-Using-Memory-on-My-Leaves- for help on what that means. Also, what queries are running during this time?

Comment: @JackChen I ran the query Show status; and attached it to the question. Most of the queries are select queries joining multiple tables and also some inserts. I did not specifically select leaf 3307 when running the query. If needed how to run on that?

Comment: To query the leaf, connect a client to the leaf node directly and run the query there. Actually SHOW STATUS EXTENDED would be better.

Comment: @JackChen I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the status output, we can see:

- 10GB total memory on the leaf node
- 7GB Alloc_durability_large

You can see what these variables mean here: https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001091386-What-Is-Using-Memory-on-My-Leaves-

Most interesting is the large amount in Alloc_durability_large, which is unusual. Do you have a large number of databases and/or partitions? (You can check by counting the number of rows in SHOW DATABASES EXTENDED on the leaf nodoe.) Each will require a fixed amount of transaction buffer memory (default is 64 MB).

Comment: Yes I have around 40 DBs which keeps growing. I ran the query and it's Memory (MBs) column showed memory for each DB. But all summed to approximately 1GB. So what is the solution for this? is it the number of DBs that causes this?

Comment: Yes. Each database and partition will require a fixed amount of transaction buffer memory (default is 64 MB). You can consider lowering the transaction-buffer system variable, or using fewer databases.

Comment: ok thanks By deleting databases, memory usage reduced. How can I change the transaction-buffer system variable? will it effect the performance?

Comment: Use http://docs.memsql.com/docs/memsql-update-config (or directly edit all memsql.cnfs) and then restart your servers. It may affect perf depending on your workload, but probably will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I really add a swap memory to the server? will it help in anyway to memsql in memory data?

Comment: Swap doesn't affect you normally. It just helps avoid Linux oom-killing you if the system's memory is overloaded.